# Can we call "Regularization" as "Constrained Optimization"?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, optimization, terminology, regularization

I have the following question on "**Regularization vs. Constrained Optimization"** :

In the context of statistical modelling, we are often taught about "Regularization" as a method of dealing with the "Bias-Variance Tradeoff". When a L1-Norm or L2-Norm Penalty Term is added to the estimation function (corresponding to the statistical model) being optimized, some of the model parameters will either "shrink" in size towards 0 - thus producing a "sparser" model that is more likely to retain its "low bias" but possible reduce its "high variance":

I have often heard of functions containing these L1-Norm and L2-Norm "Penalty Terms" being referred to as "optimization constraints" (i.e. the "feasible region" from which valid choices of model parameters can belong to has now been "altered" due to these "norm penalty constraints"):

**My Question:** **When we estimate some statistical model's parameters and the estimation equation contains some "regularization penalty term" - would it be incorrect to refer to this as an example of "constrained optimization"?** Is regularized optimization in Machine Learning and Statistical Modelling fundamentally any different (with the exception of usually being more difficult and solved using approximate stochastic iterative methods) from Constrained Optimization in Linear Programming?

[image]

Can someone please comment on this?

Thanks!

**References:**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)
- http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php?title=NLopt_Tutorial

Comment: I think *constrained optimization* is a more appropriate term.  Constraint optimization sounds like you're optimizing the constraints.

Comment: @ Demetri Pananos: thank you for this correction! I will change this right now!

Comment: This question relies on an incorrect concept of regularization.  Regularization does not explicitly introduce constraints (although it often can be reformulated as such).  This is abundantly clear in the Wikipedia article you link to. Thus it's difficult to see any sense to calling it "constrained optimization" *per se.*

Comment: @ whuber: thank you for your reply! I struggle to understand this point...are there any other references you could recommend that might explain this? Thank you so much!

Comment: What is the "point" to which you refer?  The meaning of a "constraint"?  What "regularization" is?  Something else?

Comment: @ whuber: thank you for your reply! "Regularization does not explicitly introduce constraints (although it often can be reformulated as such)." I am very confused about this: when i look at the objective function for a model that is being optimized for parameter estimation: i see a constraint (lambda parameter). So why is "regularization not explicitly introducing constraints", when I can see "constraints". Thank you so much!

Comment: The presence of lambda does not immediately imply presence of a constraint in optimization. E.g. a parameter is not constrained to lie in an interval $[a,b]$ or such. While in some cases you can reformulate the problem as a constrained optimization one (such as in the case of lasso), this is not generally true (I think, and I refer to whuber's comment, too).

Comment: By definition, a constraint restricts the potential solution to a subset of the original space.  Constraints almost always appear in the problem formulation explicitly as equalities or inequalities that need to be satisfied, or more generally as restrictions of the form $x\in \mathcal X$ where $x$ is a potential solution and $\mathcal X$ denotes the constrained solution space.  Thus, *constraints and parameters* are completely different things (whence their interrelationships through Lagrange multipliers or dual formulations tend to be interesting and useful).

Comment: The usual way to think about regularization is adding a penalty term to the objective. Hopefully, no constraints are needed. The choice of the penalty parameter is the same issue as in multi-objective optimization (weighted sum approach).

Comment: Regularization as a soft constraint: https://explained.ai/regularization/impl.html